# Can I recover my iPhone XCode project from app store?

Tags: iphone

I mistakenly deleted my Xcode project but app is published at app store. So, can I recover the code?

Answer (score 0):

The product you submit to Apple does not include the source code. Therefore Apple cannot deliver the source code back to you; it does not have it any more than you have the source code to Microsoft Word if you happen to have installed Office.